# How to change actionbarsherlock home icon

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried everything to change the icon on actionsherlock bar but it just show me android logo.
i tried this to replace icon but failed . i am using custom themes for my actionbar color.

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

here is my string.xml

```
 <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item></style><style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar"><item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar</item><item name="background">@drawable/actionbar</item><item name="android:displayOptions">showHome</item></style>
```

Here is manifest file

```
<application android:label="Myapp" 
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"> 
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.twitter.SplashScreen"
          android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme"
          />
```

I dont want to show Title on actionbar .. i just want to show Logo of my app so is there any way to change icon by coding?
thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in your activity's code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_actionbar_home);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
}
```

Comment: i tried that as i said..it wont work for me..it just show me green android logo on actionbar..

Comment: it work for me i just change the name of image and assign it again

Comment: it works good on jelly bean and ICS but in gingerbread it shows logo plus application name...i dont know why? logo plus app name on actionbar

Comment: Do you know how to set background image for listview?..i want to assign background image or background color to every item in listview..can you help me

Comment: No. Show some effort, use Google. Or hire me to do the job for you ... ;)

Comment: I already search on google..i tried to view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); but failed...than i try to assign background color tag in listview xml but it changes the hole color of list ..not individual colors

Comment: Google "android custom listview"

Comment: thanks i will search acording to that..as i am student i dont know much